# getting error while trying to install ubuntu-tv in ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: apt, software-installation, ubuntu-tv

Im trying to install Ubuntu-TV and I ran `apt-get install unity-lens-video` and it returned This error:

```
Selecting previously unselected package unity-scope-video-remote.
Preparing to unpack .../unity-scope-video-remote_0.3.15+13.10.20130920-0ubuntu1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking unity-scope-video-remote (0.3.15+13.10.20130920-0ubuntu1) ...
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any Idea to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

According to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuTV/Contributing Ubuntu-TV is only available to be installed in 12.04 (and is suggested to install in a virtual machine if you are running a newer version). I have not tried it, but you could use something like http://www.howtogeek.com/117635/how-to-install-kvm-and-create-virtual-machines-on-ubuntu/ and install Ubuntu 12.04 from the ISO and try Ubuntu-tv there.